# Многократное определение функции

Tags: c++, функции, указатели, ссылки

[image: .]

***Основной блок:***

```
    #include <string>
    #include "golf.cpp"

    //extern void setgolf(golf& g, const char* name, int hc);
    //extern int setgolf(golf& g);
    //extern void handicap(golf& g, int hc);
    //extern void showgolf(const golf& g);

    int main()
    {
        golf andy;
        golf &lol=andy;
        using namespace std;
        cout << "Vvedite name: ";
        char *name =new char[Len];
        int ch;
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Vvedite handicap: ";
        cin >> ch;
        setgolf(lol,name,ch);
        return 0;
    }
```

***Второй блок***

```
    #include <iostream>

const int Len = 40;
struct golf {
    char fullname[Len];
    int handicap;
};


void setgolf(golf &g, const char* name,int hc) {
    std::cout << "*g.fullname=" << *g.fullname << std::endl << "g.handicap=" << g.handicap;
    *g.fullname = *name;
    g.handicap = hc;
    std::cout << "*g.fullname=" << *g.fullname << std::endl << "g.handicap=" << g.handicap;
}

int setgolf(golf& g) {
    std::cout << "Vvedite handicap: ";
    std::cin >> g.handicap;
    std::cout << "Vvedite ima: ";
    std::cin.get(g.fullname, Len);
    if (std::cin) return 1;
    else return(0);
}

void handicap(golf& g, int hc) {
    g.handicap = hc;
    std::cout << "Gandicap otnine =" << hc << std::endl;
}

void showgolf(const golf& g) {
    std::cout << "Name: " << g.fullname << "  handicap: " << g.handicap << std::endl;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/error-messages/tool-errors/linker-tools-error-lnk2005?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DRU-RU%26k%3Dk(LNK2005)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во-первых, что такое "блок"? Где распологаются эти "блоки"? Во-вторых, приводите полное описание ошибок из обычного окна Output. Это гламурное новое окошко, чей скриншот вы привели, малоинформативно. И почему у вас вдруг выполняется `#include` для `.cpp` файла?

Comment: Видимо, вы компилируете 2 файла - типа main.cpp и golf.cpp (названия файлов условные). Каковой включили через `#include` в первый файл - так что все **определения** у вас теперь в двух экземплярах.

Comment: Постарался добавить новую информацию. Проверьте пожалуйста. Harry,могу я узнать,что вы имели ввиду "определения у вас теперь в двух экземпляра". Если я объявлял данные функции только в golf.cpp

Answer (score 1):

Ну так у вас в проекте файл `golf.cpp` компилируется как самостоятельный файл проекта, но при этом еще и включен в `ConsoleApplication4.cpp` через `#include`. Разумеется, получились двойственные определения.

Зачем вы включили `#include "golf.cpp"` в `ConsoleApplication4.cpp`? Чего вы пытались этим добиться?

Comment: Я хотел использовать функции из golf.cpp в ConsoleApplication4.cpp

Comment: @TEARLESS: Ну и получили в результате множественные определения. В языках С и С++ для этого пишут .h-файлы, в которые помещают только *объявления* функций. Вот это вам и нужно сделать.

Comment: Извините,но по условию задачи я должен определить второй cpp файл. Я очень благодарен вам за помощь. Решил эту проблему ,добавив static, пере функциями,тем самым предотвратил дублирование.

Comment: "Определить второй cpp файл" - это не означает *включать* этот `.cpp` файл через `#include`. Ни в коем случае. Через `static` никакого дублирования вы не предотвратили. Вы просто силой подавили ошибку. Бессмысленное дублирование при этом никуда не делось.

Answer (score -6):

Решил эту проблему ,добавив static, пере функциями,тем самым предотвратил дублирование.

Comment: Вы решили задачу не так, как это нужно делать на C++

Comment: Через `static` никакого дублирования вы не "предотвратили". Вы просто силой подавили ошибку. Бессмысленное дублирование при этом никуда не делось.

Comment: Дурацкое решение... При гангрене - побольше одеколона, чтоб не воняло.